# Why is devDependencies' pruning skipped even if NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION is true?

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

When trying to push a Node.js project to Heroku, I can find between the log lines the following one:

```
Pruning devDependencies
remote:        Skipping because NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION is 'true'
```

Now, I was expecting pruning is skipped at the opposite condition (`NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`).

Any thoughts about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behaviour of Heroku's Node.js buildpack is to install `dependencies` and `devDependencies`, build the slug, and then strip out the `devDependencies`. They'll be available during the build process but not afterwards.

[Setting `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` to `true` prevents `devDependencies` from being installed in the first place](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#only-installing-dependencies):

> You can direct Heroku to only install dependencies by setting environment variables `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true` or `YARN_PRODUCTION=true`.

Since `devDependencies` are never installed there is no need to prune them. There's nothing to strip out.

(Technically, the buildpack [skips pruning if `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` is non-null](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/99ebd7cb842f4ffa9759bf13be3beba566fa9552/lib/dependencies.sh#L216-L219); its actual value doesn't matter for this part of the logic.)

Comment: no, they are not being skipped, in fact I can find them navigating in node_modules folder by the heroku run bash command. 
Why do you say "The documentation shows that devDependencies will be skipped if NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true"? It should be the opposite.

Comment: @toninotrip, what is the exact value of `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION`? Is it `true` or `'true'`?

Comment: It is `true`, without quotes. I get it by the `heroku config:get command`, and also by revealing the config vars on the Heroku app dashboard. So weird..

Comment: Try setting it again with `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true`, just to be sure. You can also unset the variable (`heroku config:unset NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION`) to get the default behaviour of installing and then removing `devDependencies`.

Comment: ok, I will try now. The fun fact is that I need exactly this behaviour, that is not to perform pruning, but I'd like to reach this goal the "right way" and understand why it is skipping it now.

Comment: Do you have `NODE_ENV` set? If so, what's it set to?

Comment: Oh, wait, I see what's happening here. I'm going to rewrite my answer.

Comment: `NODE_ENV` set to 'production', anyway waiting for you to rewrite your answer :)

Comment: ...trying to understand your points. So the point now is that my devDependencies remained installed under node_modules (and here comes following question) and it is remaining there because of pruning skipping (due to `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true` that directly alters step 1).

Comment: Next question is: can we say, given also the first piece of documentation you quoted above, that setting `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` and unsetting it (default) produce two different outcomes? --> bcause setting it to false makes the devDependencies that were installed in that context remain "forever" there (that is what I aim), or at lest unless someone perform `npm prune` or manual deletion. Otherwise, If I had never modified `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` (that is leave it undefined), I wouldn't have had my devDependencies available at runtime. Are my assertions correct?

Comment: @toninotrip, with `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true` `devDependencies` should never be installed so there's no need to prune them and pruning is skipped. They shouldn't be on the server. Yes, `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` and unsetting `NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION` give two different results. In the first case `devDependencies` get installed and remain available. In the second case they get installed but are removed once the build is complete.