# Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react'

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I was trying to deploy my [reactjs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails) rails app on heroku.

Everything seems okay until I get this error:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
remote:        Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react'
```

The app works fine in my localhost. I tried deleting my node_modules folder then running npm install but the error persisted(only when deploying at heroku).

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react_ujs": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.14.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to deploy it. I based my answer here: [Why is devDependencies' pruning skipped even if NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION is true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550262/why-is-devdependencies-pruning-skipped-even-if-npm-config-production-is-true)

What I did was set:

```
NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION= false 
YARN_PRODUCTION = false
YARN_CONFIG_PRODUCTION = false
```

I tested changing ENV values and this what worked for me.

This can set at heroku settings under config vars

Answer (score 0):

Heroku defaults to `NODE_END=production`. How does this affect your build?

You have `@babel/preset-react` in `devDependencies`. When you do `npm i` (or `yarn`) to install packages with `NODE_ENV=production`, npm (or yarn) only installs `dependencies` (it wont install `devDependencies`).

To get around this, you can -

- either override `NODE_ENV`. (`$ NODE_ENV=development npm i`)
- Run `npm i --only=dev` before you build

To be on the safe side, revert the value on `NODE_ENV` to production when you run in production environment (Heroku in your case).